# Super-Linear Growth after Reordering

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a sequence/function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. (For the scope of this question, let $\mathbb{N} = \{ 0, 1, 2, \dots \}$.)

From $f$, we are going to create a function $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ which results from reordering $f$'s values monotonously. For this, we define the permutation $\pi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $\pi(j) = \min \big\{ i \mid f(i) = \min f(\mathbb{N} \setminus \{ \pi(0), \pi(1), \dots, \pi(j - 1) \}) \big\}$, i. e. $\pi(0)$ is the position belonging to the smallest value in the image of $f$, $\pi(1)$ is the position belonging to the second smallest value etc. with the addition, that we take the number of appearances of any value in the image of $f$ into account.

Now, set $g(n) := f(\pi(n))$. Then, $g(0)$ is the smallest value in $f(\mathbb{N})$, $g(1)$ is the second smallest etc. (again, taking the number of appearances into account).

If we assume $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} = \infty$, does this imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(n)}{n} = \infty$ for the given construction?

So far, I was neither able to prove nor disprove the implication. The problem seems to be that large values $f(n)$ can be moved very far to the right in $g$ resulting in rather small values for $\frac{g(n)}{n}$.

I would appreciate any proofs, counterexamples or hints on related lemmas/theorems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} = \infty$ is defined by $\forall C \exists n_0 \forall n\geq n_0: \frac{f(n)}{n} > C$.
Fix a $C\in \mathbb N$. Then there must exists such a $n_0$. We will show that $\frac{g(n)}{n} > C$ for all $n\geq n_0$.
Consider any $n \geq n_0$. In order to restrict us to a finite reordering, consider another sequence $\hat g : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. The sequence $\hat g$ is the result of the following procedure:

> $\hat g$ := f;
>   **while** $\hat g(\{1,\ldots, n\})$ are not the smallest n values:
>   Choose the smallest value $i\leq n$ which is not yet sorted and swap this value with its left neighbor

The algorithm runs in finitely many steps and by construction $g(i) = \hat g(i)$ for all $i\leq n$.
We will show the loop invariant $\frac{\hat g(n)}{n} > C$ for all $n\geq n_0$. This is true at the beginning,
as $\hat g$ is initialized with $f$. Now consider any swap during the algorithm. 
Let $p, p+1$ be the positions of the swap.

Case $p\geq n_0$: By the invariant,
we have $\frac{\hat g(p)}{p} > C$ and $\frac{\hat g(p+1)}{p+1} > C$. 
Since they are swapped, we must have $g(p+1) < g(p)$. 
Thus, $\frac{\hat g(p+1)}{p} > \frac{\hat g(p+1)}{p+1} > C$ and $\frac{\hat g(p)}{p+1} > \frac{\hat g(p+1)}{p+1} > C$.

Case $p+1 = n_0$: $\frac{\hat g(p+1)}{p+1} > C$ and $\hat g(p+1) < \hat g(p)$ holds. Thus, we have $\frac{\hat g(p)}{p+1} > \frac{\hat g(p+1)}{p+1} > C$.

Case $p+1<n_0$: This obviously does not change the invariant.

Thus, the invariant holds in each case.

The high-level idea of the proof is the following: Whenever a large value of $f(n)$ is moved to the right, there must have been a smaller element of the sequence on the right. However this smaller element already was large enough, so the larger element is also large enough. So it cannot happen for a value to be moved to the "very far right".